# Oracle процедуру адаптировать для SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2005

В Oracle процедуре есть такая конструкция
FOR x IN (SELECT...)
LOOP EXECUTE IMMEDIATE... END LOOP;
Как её реализовать на SQL Server 2005?
Заранее благодарен за ответ.
С уважением,
Александр

Comment: Скажем, курсором... почему нет?

Comment: Как понимаю, и далее через FETCH next?
Хорошо бы примерчик, ибо в процедурах на SQL Server нет особого навыка.

Comment: Вопрос решён. Процедура создана.

Comment: Точнее половина процедуры создана.
Осталось EXECUTE IMMEDIATE с SQL запросом с параметром, каким-то образом на SQL Server 2005 отбразить.